# I tried updating dart and now wall the lines are red

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-material

I can't seem to post an image yet but my entire `main.dart` is red including the `'package:flutter/material.dart'` and other widgets.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Certain questions here are more likely to get helpful answers. Questions that don’t show what you’ve tried are generally more difficult to answer - people often skip right over them. So show your code for best results. If you encounter a specific technical problem during that attempt, we can help with that, and we want to - that’s part of why we’re here. To learn more about helping us help you, please start with [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). If you’re really ambitious, read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: can you post your code?

Comment: try 'flutter pub get' in your terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Try `flutter clean` and then `flutter pub get`.

If that doesn't work, you can try upgrading your Flutter SDK (again?) like so: `flutter upgrade`.

You can also run `flutter doctor` to see a list of possible issues with your code.

Comment: @RoaringCamels Awesome! If it worked, make sure to upvote/mark it as correct for users in the future :)